# Elm navigation prevent cannot GET

Tags: elm

I have been playing around with the Elm navigational packages, at the moment I am working with the Hop framework, and I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the `cannot GET /<url>` messages without the pound signs in front of the url (example: `#<url>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling this might be a server configuration issue. For #-less url's to work, you need to configure your server to serve the same `.html` regardless of the request URL. Once that is served, your Elm app can load and take it from there.

Comment: Then my feeling is confirmed, I'll try to get it working as soon as I am home

Answer (score 2):

To add to Peter Szerzo's answer, I found [an issue at the Github page of browser-sync](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204) page about roughly the same problem as I had. The solution is as follows:

```js
const modRewrite = require("connect-modrewrite");

gulp.task("serve", () => {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        middleware: [
            modRewrite([
                "!\\.\\w+$ /index.html [L]"
            ]),
        ]
    }
}
```

If you're going to use Apache or Nginx, you need to use a different solution of course. This is browser-sync specific.

**Update**

I ran into another issue where the solution above would not work, since it would fetch the items again from a different location. For example: manually navigating to `/blog/1` would work perfectly fine, since there aren't any HTTP requests when changing to that location, but when reloading the page, the page would fetch the files from `/blog`, which the solution above did not handle. This is how I fixed the latter issue:

```js
middleware: [
    (req, res, next) => {
        const splitRequestUrl = req.url.split("/");
        const fileName = splitRequestUrl[splitRequestUrl.length - 1];

        //I have a seperate paths file
        //Change paths.serve to whatever folder you want to specify as your base folder
        if (fs.existsSync(path.join(process.cwd(), paths.serve, fileName)))
            req.url = `/${fileName}`;
        else
            req.url = "/";

        next();
    }
]
```